# how to fix key error in listing content from a s3 bucket in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have following piece of code, that utilizes list_objects_v2 from boto3. I get an error => keyError : 'Contents'. I am assuming if name of the file i'm passing doesn't exist , it throws this error.

```
import boto3
s3_R = boto3.client('s3')
s3_b = s3_R.Bucket("MyBucket")

response = s3_R.list_objects_v2(Bucket=s3_b, Prefix='myfilename')
for obj in response['contents']:
   file = obj['key']
   print(file)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `Contents`, not `contents`, assuming some objects are returned:

```
response = s3_R.list_objects_v2(Bucket='MyBucket', Prefix='myfilename')

if 'Contents' in response:
   for obj in response['Contents']:
      file = obj['Key']
      print(file)
else:
   print("No objects returned")
```

Comment: thanks. does it need to be 'Contents' as well in this line =>  for obj in response['contents']:

Comment: @kyagu Yes, I eddited the answer.

Comment: in my case i have "Contents", but same error